# Error de Sintaxis en MYSQL y JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, java-8

espero que me pueda ayudar. Estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas en JAVA y MySQL. Al momento de eliminar un registro de un cliente, me gustaría que los ids se ordenaran, es decir, que si elimino el registro numero 5, mi lista de clientes no quede en 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,etc...

Al parecer encontré la solución a este problema mediante este código.

```
SET @n := 0;
UPDATE cliente SET idCliente = @n := (@n + 1);
ALTER TABLE cliente AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Al ejecutarlo directamente con phpMyAdmin funciona de maravilla. Pero al hacerlo desde mi código JAVA me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Implemento esto en el siguiente método.

```
    public boolean enumerarClientes() {
    String SQL = "SET @n = 0; "
            + "UPDATE cliente SET idCliente = @n := (@n + 1); "
            + "ALTER TABLE cliente AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";

    try {
        con = cn.getConexion();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.execute();

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Llamo el método enumerarClientes() aquí.

```
 if (cliSQL.enumerarClientes()) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se han ordenado los clientes!.");

  } else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar Ordenar Clientes. Por favor, intente de nuevo.");
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar :). Saludos!!

Comment: Asumiendo que es un cambio cosmético con valor didáctico, prueba agregar a tu cadena de conexión `allowMultiQueries=true`. No necesitas una sentencia preparada para este caso, puede ser una sentencia simple `con.createStatement()` y sus métodos `addBatch()` y `executeBatch()`.

Comment: Gracias, quedó solucionado! :)

Comment: @Sal deberías poner tu respuesta para que la pregunta no quede sin contestar puesto que solucionó el problema según comentario del autor (quien debería aceptarla luego). Cuestión de formalización de pregunta - respuesta.